# Size based scaling for symbology in StoryMaps journal

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, scale, story-map

Is there a way to have size based scaling for symbology StoryMaps journal?

Scale based sizing of symbols works in ArcGIS Pro, and web map has been uploaded to my organization, however when viewing in map view or storymaps symbols stay the same size

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow the link below to use scale based symbology for layers in ArcGIS Online web maps

[Apply scale-based symbology to view different feature geometries at different map scales in ArcGIS Online](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000019473)

Once you create your web maps with the desired symbology try using it in the story map journal template.